# How can I apply token color changes to existing vscode color theme?

Tags: themes, editor, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make vscode theme by modifying existing color theme.
and having trouble with applying token color changes to existing theme.

I saw official guide of vscode(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes) and tried like below.

but lint says 'Property entity.name.function.member is not allowed.' and not applied to current workbench.

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBar.background": "#2a2b30",
    "[Darktooth]": {
      "entity.name.function.member": "#347890"
    }
  },
```

I know there is a way to change editor with specifying all tokens, but I think using existing theme would save time.

Also I would like to apply color to some workbenches(workspace) not the entire editor.

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#595436",
    "strings": "#D5ECE2",
    "functions": "#1ee9a5",
    "textMateRules": [
      {
      "scope": "storage.modifier.ts",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#FFFFFF"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope":["entity.name.function.member", "meta.object-literal.key.js"],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#A1E2AA",
        }
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: you can't change theme color with `workbench.colorCustomizations`, use `editor.tokenColorCustomizations`, these can be scoped to themes too, just place the modifications in `.vscode/setting.json` of the workspace

Comment: Thanks! didn't know I can scope to themes at tokenColorCustomizations. I fixed it